# Exclude builtins when in mapped conditional type

Tags: typescript

Consider the following...

```js
type Boxed<T> = { value: T }

type Unboxed<T> = T extends Boxed<infer R>
  ? R
  : T extends Record<any, any>
  ? { [P in keyof T]: Unboxed<T[P]> }
  : T

function unbox(v: Record<any, any>): Unboxed {
}
```

`unbox` is a function that accepts an object of any type and recursively unboxed all of the boxed objects. For example...

```
const output = unbox({ foo: { value: 'foo' }, bar: 'bar' })

output === { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }
```

This works well, unless one of the properties is an *unboxed* builtin that also matches `extends Record<any, any>`. For example, Dates, RegExp, Map, Set, etc. Instead of mapping the builtin, the mapping continues over the prototype. This causes a type mismatch as the interface matches, but not the actual builtin type.

For example, the following line of code...

```js
const unboxed: { date: Date } = Unboxed<{ date: Date }>
```

...throws this error...

```
Type '{ date: { toString: {}; toDateString: {}; toTimeString: {}; toLocaleString: {}; toLocaleDateString: {}; toLocaleTimeString: {}; valueOf: {}; getTime: {}; getFullYear: {}; getUTCFullYear: {}; getMonth: {}; ... 32 more ...; getVarDate: {}; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ date: Date; }'.\n  Types of property 'date' are incompatible.\n    Property '[Symbol.toPrimitive]' is missing in type '{ toString: {}; toDateString: {}; toTimeString: {}; toLocaleString: {}; toLocaleDateString: {}; toLocaleTimeString: {}; valueOf: {}; getTime: {}; getFullYear: {}; getUTCFullYear: {}; getMonth: {}; ... 32 more ...; getVarDate: {}; }' but required in type 'Date'."
```

How can I use a recursive conditional mapped type that will *only* perform recursion on plain objects?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how one would expect to tell the difference between "built-in" object types and "plain" object types in the type system, which doesn't have such notions.  Possibly you could build an large hard-coded union of built-in types to check against and make `Unboxed<T>` have a clause like `T extends Map<any, any> | Set<any> | Date | RegExp | ...`.  Yuck.

Another possible way to go (that you'd need to test heavily before putting into any production code) is to make an assumption like this: let's say I use my `Unboxed<T>` on a type `T` and I get a new type to which `T` is still assignable.  That probably means that `Unboxed<T>` didn't actually unbox anything anywhere inside of `T`.  If so, then I should probably just use `T` instead of what `Unboxed<T>` gives me.  So if `T extends Unboxed<T>`, then return `T`.  That kind of check might be translated to this:

```
type Unboxed<T> =
    T extends Boxed<infer R> ? R :
    T extends Function ? T :
    T extends object ? (
        { [P in keyof T]: Unboxed<T[P]> } extends infer O ? T extends O ? T : O : never) :
    T
```

(where I've also decided that `Function` compatible `T` values should not try to be unboxed).  So if `T` is `Boxed<R>` for some `R`, we get `R`.  If `T` is a function or primitive type, we get `T`.  Otherwise, if `T` is some object type, we calculate `{[P in keyof T]: Unboxed<T[P]>}` and assign it to `O` for easy re-use.  Finally, we compare `O` to `T`.  If `O` is some wider version of `T`, use `T`.  Otherwise, use `O`.

Given the following `Example` interface:

```
interface Example {
    str: string;
    num: number;
    box: Boxed<{ foo: string }>;
    fun: () => { value: string };
    dat: Date;
    subProp: {
        str: string;
        dat: Date;
        map: Map<string, number>;
        set: Set<boolean>;
        reg: RegExp;
        box: Boxed<{ bar: number }>;
    }
}
```

This is what you get when you unbox it:

```
type UnboxedExample = Unboxed<Example>;
/*
type UnboxedExample = {
    str: string;
    num: number;
    box: {
        foo: string;
    };
    fun: () => {
        value: string;
    };
    dat: Date;
    subProp: {
        str: string;
        dat: Date;
        map: Map<string, number>;
        set: Set<boolean>;
        reg: RegExp;
        box: {
            bar: number;
        };
    };
}
*/
```

All of the built-in types are unchanged, and so is the `fun` function-valued property (note that this means the return type of `fun` is still `{value: string}` and not `string`, since we're not unboxing function return values, right?).  The property `box` and `subProp.box` are unboxed as expected too.

---

This is probably the closest I could get to what you're asking for.  Again, you'd want to thoroughly test this before using it... there are weird edge cases that don't play nicely with this definition.  The assumption that `T extends Unboxed<T>` implies that there's nothing to unbox inside `T` can be wrong, for objects with specially-crafted properties that look like `U & Boxed<U>` for some `U`.  Like this one:

```
interface What {
    foo: {
        bar: string,
        value: { bar: string }
    }
}
type Wait = Unboxed<What>;
// type Wait = What
```

Here, the `foo` property of `What` looks like `{bar: string} & Boxed<{bar: string}>`, so the definition of `Unboxed<What>` erroneously decides that `What` should be returned as-is instead of unboxing it.  Will you have such weird types in your code?  Probably not.  But still, it's something to watch out for.

---

Okay, hope that helps or at least gives you some idea how to proceed.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gDwgEwDwBUB8UC8UDeUAbgIYA2ArhAFxTpQC+AsAFCuiRQCqAdgEaIUGbDlZRxdKBATAIPZAGdYgtAEseAMwgAnKACVsAfn1RqYifWmz5SgGIUeAY2Cq4PKMfpmWEyVbmKUHB8AFYQzh5QABTmvuKEANoAClDqUADWECBwGnQAurS8Akho6Ml52AxSMgFK6lq6APKRljU2UM2eph3dPBBEOgCUprF0rKzqstoaJI7QAKIIJAC2YGTQ+KMKwNq029rqAOYA3KM8FMu058t8Oqc+EsW08CWohBpwcHs7R4yY974NA5aFFhjhsIRSJQaFB9r8GACJMgSMBaAARFEQRHiBQUPhJbRwMC0TYPOKwnbfA48E6jXzI1FQDGybFxZYkYlQACyHNQcJpABooNdbtp-nSJAoIIyAMrS1ACODrEg8cVkuLaCCHWh6LWLMCs3xPZSvQh8Ei7YUXUV-VnMFj29jgaBFFSLFZraB4V2vd2rdZqgD0AConZwfSg-Z7cAQtpSKdTaerrldrXdRsbSeTxB8vgmjnbWUCeCCwRCJeIoVQqQXRgjRgz0ZjWbj8YTOVns-sazTDUiUU2WRWoOzOTywHyfoKrTcdGrs7DpbQ5cAFZ9laq++JNdr9HqEAbh5nh0aLanZ9ot4xC6x7cHA+MWJMdDM5lAAOoACxRsfVuZJR5nvmgrDlWMJmkB-KHIwda3mG0DviQqjADGEZoF+KJBoGUAcAhSEoXgGHAI+QA)